How to pass ConfigurationName parameter in az vm run-command
I have 2 scenarios

Execute test.ps1 powershell present inside azure VM - Works fine
Execute test.ps1 powershell directly from azure devops repository - Error

Contents of testfile.ps1
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM table" -ServerInstance "instance" -Database "Dbname"

Scenario 1: To execute a powershell on azure windows machine below command works perfectly
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  inputs:
    Machines: 'servername'
    UserName: 'username'
    UserPassword: 'password'
    InlineScript: |
      $Username = "username"
      $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
      $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $Password)
      Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName configname -ScriptBlock {D:\test.ps1}
    CommunicationProtocol: 'Http'

Scenrio 2: To execute powershell directly from repository
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'testrun'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subname'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name servername-g RGname --scripts "@testfile.ps1"

For scenario 2 facing below error
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot open database \"DBname\" requested by the login. The login failed.\nLogin failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM'

In Scenario 1 to avoid NTAUTHORITY authority (double-hop) issue we were using parameter ConfigurationName with stored credential in invoke-command
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -Credential $cred -ConfigurationName configname -ScriptBlock {D:\test.ps1}

I am not sure how to use this ConfigurationName parameter in az vm run-command.
Could someone please help

I noticed that in the Invoke-Command of Scenario 1, you passed the Username and password as credential. But in your az vm run-command invoke command of Scenario 2, you didn't pass any credential to login to the SQL. This may cause it logins with the system account (‘NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM’) which don't have the permission. Can you try to add the username and password, or ConnectionString for Invoke-Sqlcmd command in testfile.ps1 to make sure the command can connect to the Sql?

If I am passing credentials in invoke-sqlcmd since we use windows authentication user not SQL authentication I am getting access denied to login SQL . Is there any way to pass credentials using az vm run command to login server with that account (This account has access to connect to DB)

Thanks for your update. I checked the document of az vm run-command invoke command, it seems that it doesn't have a parameter to pass the credentials. Please check if the workaround in bryanbcook's answer can help the issue.

There's a key difference between these approaches:

PowerShellOnTargetMachine@3 executes a PowerShell command on the build agent to establish a PSRemoting session to the remote box. Once connected, it executes the InlineScript interactively on that machine using the credentials specified. The Invoke-Command PowerShell cmdlet doesn't need the -ComputerName or the -Credentials parameter because the InlineScript is already executing on that machine as that user.

AzureCLI@2 executes a shell script on the build agent to authenticate to Azure with a service-principal that has permissions assigned to the Azure resource. The az vm run-command is equivalent to using the Azure Portal to use the Run Command blade to pass instructions to the virtual machine which are then executed by an Azure-installed plugin that is pre-installed on the Azure VM. The plugin executes the command in an administrative session (NT Authority\System). You can pass parameters to your script file but cannot specify session connection information or user account details.


I would typically use the az vm run-command option to enable PSRemoting, copy the desired scripts to the machine and then use PowerShellOnTargetMachine to invoke them using a windows account that has been explicitly granted login permissions to that machine:
variables:
# put the username and password in a variable group 'secrets'
# so that the password isn't in plain-text in the yaml file.
- group: secrets

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Enable Remoting'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subname'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az vm run-command invoke `
         --name servername ` 
         -g RGname `
         --command-id EnableRemotePS

- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachine@3
  inputs:
    Machines: 'servername'
    UserName: '$(Machine_Username)'
    UserPassword: '$(Machine_Password)'
    InlineScript: |
       # the "." is an alias for Invoke-Command
       . D:\script.ps1 
  

